# how to debug cache related code in django

Tags: django

I am trying to apply cache in my Django project using memcache.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

I am applying per view cache as below:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/default/$', cache_page(60 * 15)(default_view), name='default_view')
```

I am trying to dedug the code in my IDE.

I found the following function at lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py

```
def cache_page(timeout, *, cache=None, key_prefix=None):

    return decorator_from_middleware_with_args(CacheMiddleware)(
        cache_timeout=timeout, cache_alias=cache, key_prefix=key_prefix
    )
```

I tried to create a stop at return line. But I found when i refresh the url the code does not stop at this line.

Comment: `cache_page` returns a decorator. This line runs once in the `urls.py` when the view is decorated (`cache_page(60 * 15)(default_view)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already @Alasdair mentioned in the comment if you set a breakpoint in `cache_page` body your it will be executed only once.

If you want to follow the request you should set your breakpoint in `CacheMiddleware` methods either in [`process_response`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/middleware/cache.py#L74) or [`process_request`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/middleware/cache.py#L127)

Comment: I have a breakpoint in __init__ of FetchFromCacheMiddleware, why didnt it stop there. but when i put a break point inside process_request it worked